# Setting dbname conditionally from PostgreSQL block

Tags: database, postgresql

I have to connect to a db if that is present, and if it is not present we have to create a db with a different name and connect to that. Hence we need a connection to a db whose name will vary based on the above condition.

My current code is like :

```
DO $$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'xdb') THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Database already exists';
   ELSE
      RAISE NOTICE 'Database does not exist';
      PERFORM dblink_exec('dbname=' || current_database()||' user=puser'  -- current db
                        , 'CREATE DATABASE "ydb" with owner puser');
   END IF;
END $$;
\connect 'xdb' ---->> This DB should be either xdb or ydb based on the above condition
## Other insert statements
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?
We are using Postgres 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or possibly:

```
select case when exists (select 1 from pg_database where datname = 'xdb') 
          then 'xdb'::text
          else 'ydb' 
       end as conndb \gset
\connect :conndb
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is a `psql` script.

You can use conditional processing in `psql`:

```
\if :reconnect
\connect xdb
\endif
```

The variable can be set with

```
\set reconnect 1
```

in the appropriate branch.